# What does search bar invoke when to open a software

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys

I installed a GUI dictionary - goldendict.

It could be opened from terminal

```
me@me~$ goldendict
QFileSystemWatcher::removePaths: list is empty
QFileSystemWatcher::removePaths: list is empty
```

or could be opened from search in Press Super Key

[image]

What happened , when open a software from the search shortcut?

Does it run a subshell to open a software like goldendict as

```
 me@me:~$ (goldendict 2&>/dev/null &)
```

Does it invoke such a command?

Comment: It invokes the command specified in the `Exec=...` line in the corresponding desktop entry, which is a file with `.desktop` extension in either `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`. You can open that file with a text editor to view its contents.

Comment: I would assume the systemd tasks responsible for this checks the desktop file on what to execute. `ps -ef | goldendict` would tell you most of what you want and you can backtrack the process id to find the source of the command.